# Very long login times in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, network, user-account, login, network-user

I am experiencing an issue with OS X 10.8.3, where it takes a very long time to login. It seems like it has something to do with which network I am connected to.

Explanation of the issue:

- I get home from the office and wake my MacBook Air up from sleep
- I login with my regular account (in these groups: Admin, Managed, Mobile)
- It can anywhere 15 seconds and several minutes before I get logged in

While I'm at the office, it takes less than 1 second to login; it's pretty much instantaneous. The interesting thing is that, it seems like it only occurs the first time I login from home, or subsequent times if the computer has been sleeping for a longer period of time.

It seems like it's somehow related to which wired/wireless network I am connected to; as if it's trying to authenticate with something before logging me in. I've tried many different things (turning on/off wireless, VPN, changing user groups, etc.) but I haven't been able to determine the source of the problem.

Has anyone here experienced something similar?

Many thanks in advance,

– Leif

Comment: so you can login fine (in seconds) without network

Comment: did you try logging out from work network before going home? it might be it is somehow looking for work network it was on before going to sleep.

Comment: let me get that, going from home to work no problem, going from work to home problem. what network activity does your MBA does at work? also try turning the MBA OFF, not just sleep mode.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll give it a try. I haven't tried logging off explicitly. I'll try that next week :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mention it is/was a work account. Also that it is a managed account. Would you happen to be connecting up to an Active Directory or other directory account? If so, your directory server could be specifying that your account try and connect up with a network share on login. If your connection is wireless or something that passes login credentials in order to authenticate to the network, this may well create significant lag on login.

To test, fire up Terminal and enter:

```
dsconfigad -show
```

If the "Mount home as sharepoint" value is set to Enabled, your account is likely trying to connect to a share on login. To prevent this, simple run the following command:

```
dsconfigad -sharepoint disable
```

Note: this is all assume Active Directory connection, being one of the more popular enterprise/work domain services.

Comment: I approve that this works magically for me.